# Find ISP/IP address by geographic location?

Tags: ip, ip-address, isp

I'm trying to find an ISP or IP address by geographic location, Is this possible?

Comment: What, precisely are you looking for?  If you want to find any ISP or IP in a given country or region, that should be easy enough with Google and IP block reservation records.  If you're looking for a more comprehensive list, that could be trickier.

Comment: I am looking for IP or ISP of a particular geographic location. Etc `123 Address St. .San Diego, California`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get the kind of detail you want, unless you are the ISP and they are your client.

On Law and Order when they make one call to find out where an email was sent from actually takes weeks and involved warrants and cooperation from the ISP and sifting through logs.

The reason is that IP blocks are handed to ISPs and they are free to give them to whoever they wish without reporting it back to a central location.

Answer (score 4):

Since the reverse lookup is possible (accuracy varies) using IP2Location databases then there is no reason for you not to be able to find IP (and using IP the ISP) by location.

1. Get one of the GeoIP databases - usually the most precise variant (IP2City or similar) includes latitude and longitude.
2. Query by geographical location and get IP blocks
3. Run whois on IP to find out who is it assigned to
4. Filter the result against known ISP list

Comment: This may work for remote locations but if the address is in a city you will still end up with a list of dozens of ISPs and hundreds of thousands of IP addresses.

Comment: It will be much harder for highly populated areas, but it really depends on quality of GeoIP database - Google can often pinpoint my location based on IP alone with 100 meter accuracy.
Numbet of results won't be as high as you describe: for performance reasons GeoIP databases operate mostly on IP blocks/ranges, not separate IPs.

tl;dr; It all depends on GeoIP database, but most likely you will end up with list of all the ip in a city.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://www.countryipblocks.net/ip_aggregation_beta.php is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: $60 (for one month) is a bit pricey if you just want to do a couple of lookups to test the concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IP address and want to figure out the rough (city or zip level) location, then you can use a service like mine, IPinfo.io, which will return location details along with things like company and IP type:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8?token=allthethings
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0840",
  "postal": "94035",
  "phone": "650",
  "asn": {
    "asn": "AS15169",
    "name": "Google LLC",
    "domain": "google.com",
    "route": "8.8.8.0/24",
    "type": "hosting"
  },
  "company": {
    "name": "Google LLC",
    "domain": "google.com",
    "type": "hosting"
  }
}
```

If instead you want to know which ISPs serve an area you can use a site like this which shows you provides for a given zip code: https://www.highspeedinternet.com/providers